# Combine enumerate + itertools.izip in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools, enumerate

I would like to iterate + enumerate over two lists in Python. The following code looks ugly. Is there any better solution?

```
for id, elements in enumerate(itertools.izip(as, bs)):
  a = elements[0]
  b = elements[1]
  # do something with id, a and b
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can assign a and b during the for loop:

```
for id, (a, b) in enumerate(itertools.izip(as, bs)):
  # do something with id, a and b
```

Comment: You can trust Python to have a nice and simple solution :).

Answer (score 12):

You could use `itertools.count` instead of `enumerate`:

```
for id_, a, b in itertools.izip(itertools.count(), as_, bs):
  # do something with id_, a and b
```

Note that I've changed the variable names slightly to avoid a reserved word and the name of a builtin.

Comment: Nice change of variable names in accordance with PEP-8, bu using `itertools.count` over `enumerate` is not actually an improvement.

Comment: IMHO it is an improvement, because you can use the `itertools.izip(itertools.count(), as_, bs)` experssion as an argument of `multiprocessing.pool.map_async()`, which is not convenient with the for loop.